# Why can't generic types have explicit layout?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, clr, unsafe

If one tries to make a generic struct with the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` attribute, using the struct generates an exception at runtime:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'foo' from assembly 'bar' because generic types cannot have explicit layout.

I've been having a hard time finding any evidence that this restriction even exists. The [`Type.IsExplicitLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isexplicitlayout.aspx) docs strongly imply that it is allowed and supported. Does anyone know why this isn't allowed? I can't think of any reason why generic types would make it less verifiable. It strikes me as an edge case that they simply didn't bother to implement.

Here's [an example](http://pastebin.com/ZSz37Cu6) of why explicit generic layout would be useful:

```cs
public struct TaggedUnion<T1,T2>
{
    public TaggedUnion(T1 value) { _union=new _Union{Type1=value}; _id=1; }
    public TaggedUnion(T2 value) { _union=new _Union{Type2=value}; _id=2; }

    public T1 Type1 { get{ if(_id!=1)_TypeError(1); return _union.Type1; } set{ _union.Type1=value; _id=1; } }
    public T2 Type2 { get{ if(_id!=2)_TypeError(2); return _union.Type2; } set{ _union.Type2=value; _id=2; } }

    public static explicit operator T1(TaggedUnion<T1,T2> value) { return value.Type1; }
    public static explicit operator T2(TaggedUnion<T1,T2> value) { return value.Type2; }
    public static implicit operator TaggedUnion<T1,T2>(T1 value) { return new TaggedUnion<T1,T2>(value); }
    public static implicit operator TaggedUnion<T1,T2>(T2 value) { return new TaggedUnion<T1,T2>(value); }

    public byte Tag {get{ return _id; }}
    public Type GetUnionType() {switch(_id){ case 1:return typeof(T1);  case 2:return typeof(T2);  default:return typeof(void); }}

    _Union _union;
    byte _id;
    void _TypeError(byte id) { throw new InvalidCastException(/* todo */); }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct _Union
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public T1 Type1;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public T2 Type2;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
TaggedUnion<int, double> foo = 1;
Debug.Assert(foo.GetUnionType() == typeof(int));
foo = 1.0;
Debug.Assert(foo.GetUnionType() == typeof(double));
double bar = (double) foo;
```

**Edit:**

To be clear, note that layouts aren't verified at compile time even if the struct isn't generic. Reference overlap and x64 differences are detected at runtime by the CLR: http://pastebin.com/4RZ6dZ3S
I'm asking why generics are restricted when the checks are done at runtime either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of the issue is genericity and verifiability, and a design based on type constraints. The rule that we can't overlap references (pointer) with value types is an implicit, multi-parameter constraint. So, we know the CLR is smart enough to verify this in non-generic cases... why not generic? Sounds attractive.

A correct generic type definition is one that is verifiable to work today for any type that exists (within the constraints) and any that will be defined in the future. *[1] CLR via C#, Richter* The compiler verifies the open generic type definition on its own, considering any type constraints you specify to narrow the possible type arguments.

In absence of a more specific type constraint, for `Foo<T,U>`, T and U each represent both the union of all possible value and reference types, and the `interface` common to all those types (the base `System.Object`). If we want to make T or U more specific, we can add primary and secondary type constraints. In the latest version of C#, the most specific we can constrain by is a class or an interface. struct or primitive type constraints are not supported.

We cant currently say:

1. where only `struct` or `value type`
2. where T if T is a sealed type

Ex:

```
public struct TaggedUnion<T1, T2>
    where T1 : SealedThing   // illegal
```

so we have no way of defining a generic type that is verifiable to never violate the overlapping rule for all types within `T` and `U`. Even if we could constrain by struct, you can still derive a struct with reference fields such that for some type in the future, `T<,>` wouldn't be correct.

So what we are really asking here is `why don't generic types allow implicit type constraints based on code within the class?`; explicit layout is an internal implementation detail that imposes restrictions on which combinations of `T1` and `T2` are legal. In my opinion, that isn't consistent with the design that depends on type constraints. It violates the clean contract of the generic type system as designed. So why even go through the trouble of imposing a type constraint system in the design in the first place, if we intend to break it? We might as well toss it out and replace it with exceptions.

With the current state of things:

1. Type constraints are visible metadata of the open generic type
2. Verification of the generic type `Foo<T,U>` is performed on the open definition `F<,>` once. For each bound type instance of `Foo<t1,u1>`, t1 and u1 are checked for type correctness against the constraints. There is no need to reverify the code for the class and methods for `Foo<t1,u1>`.

All of this is "As Far As I Know"

There is no hard technical reason why every generic type instantiation could not be semantically analyzed for correctness (C++ is evidence of that) but it would seem to break the design in place.

**TL;DR**

Without breaking or supplementing the existing type constraint design there is no way for this to be verifiable.

Perhaps, combined with appropriate new type constraints, we might see it in the future.

Comment: For the record, the same kind of "imposed restrictions" could be implemented by throwing from the static constructor. (And I wouldn't be surprised to see that done in practice since generic constraints are absurdly underpowered.) But I guess I wouldn't be surprised if that really was their rationale for this limitation.

Comment: @DBN - My guess is that is indeed the rationale, otherwise one could argue that the type constraint system could be tossed out in place of exceptions. I also agree with you, they are underpowered. On the bright side, C# / CTS implementations are much easier to write compared to C++. As a compiler writer, I can realistically have a chance at implementing my own language with CTS generics without assistance. With C++ templates, you better have a team with you. I have to admit, C# is a relatively clean design.

Comment: I don't see any nice path to adding any additional kinds of generic constraints to the type system, which assumes a very solidly fixed set of non-inheritable ones [new, struct, and class]. While it might be helpful to have a constraint for e.g. "copyable as value" (making it possible to define structures that *weren't*), no generic constraints presently demands it, and thus no existing generic type would be able to satisfy it. What would probably be necessary would be to have an anti-constraint, such that structures that weren't copyable-as-value could *only* be passed to generic parameters...

Comment: ...which *had* a `NeedNotBeCopyableAsValue` "constraint" in the metadata [a constraint which all types would fulfil, since its purpose would be to to nullify a constraint that would otherwise be applied by default].

Answer (score 10):

It's specified in ECMA 335 (CLI), partition II, section II.10.1.2:

> explicit: The layout of the fields is explicitly provided (§II.10.7). However, a generic type shall not have explicit layout.

You can imagine how it could be awkward - given that the size of a type parameter depends on the type parameter, you could get some decidedly odd effects... a reference field isn't allowed to overlap with a built-in value type or another reference, for example, which would be hard to guarantee as soon as unknown sizes are involved. (I haven't looked into how it works out for 32-bit vs 64-bit references, which have a similar but slightly different issue...)

I suspect the specification could have been written to make some more detailed restrictions - but making it a simple blanket restriction on all generic types is considerably simpler.

Comment: Regular structs can already vary at runtime. (See: IntPtr) Even if it wasn't generic, verification that there is no overlap between reference and value types is already handled exclusively by the CLR: http://pastebin.com/4RZ6dZ3S What "more detailed restrictions" would need to be made for generics if the rule was lifted?

Comment: @DBN I wonder why there is a rule about generic types, then, as the CLR checks every type when loaded.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Yeah, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: I can certainly understand why `LayoutKind.Explicit` would not work with a non-class constrained generic.  Would you see any semantic difficulties with allowing it on class-constrained generics if generic-type references were assumed incompatible with anything else?

Comment: @supercat: What do you mean by "incompatible" exactly? How can the compiler work out whether a layout is valid? Or is that entirely left to the CLR at execution time? (I genuinely don't know what the current state is.)

Comment: @DBN: The more detailed restrictions would be a more complicated set of what is and isn't valid. For example, suppose `T` was itself a value type with explicit layout... or suppose there are two type parameters, both of which have explicit layout, and which overlap in the layout of the generic type. I suspect it gets sufficiently complicated that it's easier just to prohibit it. I'm far from an expert on this specific area, but I know there are plenty of places where a *possible* feature has been excluded to make a simpler global ban.

Comment: I don't see how complicated layouts are a problem that only apply to generics, though. The CLR code to flatten a nested struct hierarchy and verify the layout should be share-able between regular and generic verifiers...

Comment: @DBN: I'd say it's more that it gets significantly worse with generics. In the end, we're speculating at this point - I've provided evidence of the restriction existing, but beyond that it's guesswork, at least on my part.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If T is a value type with explicit layout, then it wouldn't be a class-constrained generic, and I see no way for `LayoutKind.Explicit` to work with such things.  On the other hand, if `T` is class-constrained then the size of a `T` would be constant, meaning that the type of `T` would not affect the location of anything else.  If fields of type `T` were not allowed to overlay anything except other fields of type `T`, then a layout which could be valid with any type `T` would be valid for all of them.

Comment: @DBN: The .NET Runtime requires/assumes that if a type would be legitimate for some combination of generic type arguments which meets its constraints, then the type must/will be legitimate for all such combinations. This ensures that the validity of a type `Foo<T>` can be evaluated by independently determining the validity of `Foo<>` once (without regard for `T`) and determining whether `T` abides by any constraints specified by `Foo<T>`.

Comment: @supercat - You said what I tried to say in my answer very concisely. Maybe you should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The design of the .NET framework makes certain assumptions about generic types would would make it essentially impossible to allow an explicit-layout structure to have any fields whose size might vary based upon generic type parameters.  Perhaps the most fundamental is this:

- If there exists any combination of type arguments for which a generic type definition would be valid, it may be presumed valid for all combinations of arguments which satisfy its specified constraints.

Consequently, it would be impossible for .NET to allow an explicit-layout structure to use passed-in generic type that wasn't constrained to `class` as the type of any field other than the very last one.  Further, the use of generic value type which used the passed-in generic type as an argument must be constrained in the same was as the passed-in type itself.

I don't think there would be any particular problem with allowing an explicit-layout structure to have a *class-constrained* generic type parameter if *nothing* was allowed to overlay any field of that type or of any value type which used it as a type argument, and such a field, if not known to be of reference type, had to be the last thing in the structure.

On the other hand, most of the "safe" usage cases could be handled better by having a non-explicit-layout structure which contained the generic type, and have one or more explicit-layout structures nestled within it.  Such an approach could semantically do everything that could be done with the explicit-layout structures.  The only annoyance would be having to add an extra level of indirection in the source code when accessing nested members, and the remedy for that would not be to allow generic explicit-layout structures, but rather to provide a means via which a structure that contains another structure could create aliases for inner-structure members.

As an example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct _UnionLongAnd2Ints
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int LowerWord;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public int UpperWord;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public long Value;
}
public struct LongTwoIntsUnionAndSomethingElse<T>
{
  UnionLongAnd2Ints UnionPart;
  T OtherPart;
}
```

Here the generic structure contains a 64-bit value which is overlaid on two 32-bit values, but it should be verifiable because the explicitly-laid-out part doesn't have anything generic.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean about the nested explicit structures. What would they contain? Is that any different from the nested explicit layout structure in my example? (_Union)

Comment: @DBN: See example above.