# Comparer for dictionary of System.Enum without boxing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection

I am facing problem when I am trying to create dictionary, where key is System.Enum. Problem is, that dictionary like this allocates garbage because default EqualityComparer is not one of the best. I tryed to write my own comparer, but without any success. Is it somehow possible?

```
    public enum MyEnum
{
    One, Two, Three
}

public Dictionary<Enum, string> dict = new Dictionary<Enum, string>();

public void Test()
{
    this.dict.Add(MyEnum.One, "One");
    this.dict.Add(MyEnum.Two, "Two");
    this.dict.Add(MyEnum.Three, "Three");

    string result;
    this.dict.TryGetValue(MyEnum.Two, out result); // <-- memory alocation :-(
}
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in your Dictionary declaration?  Your enum is `MyEnum`, but your Dictionary is `Dictionary<Enum, string>`

Comment: Why is your dictionary type `<Enum, string>` and not `<MyEnum, string>`?

Comment: Because my dictionary is stored in ma base class and Iam filling it in derived class everytime with different enums

Comment: Then why not use generics to specify the enum type?

Comment: Can you explain it little more? Here is code what I need to make work without garbage alocation https://dotnetfiddle.net/lL1QTD

Comment: No idea about GC but this is what I meant https://dotnetfiddle.net/U20IUB

Comment: Is this for Unity3d?

Comment: Yes it is for unity,

Comment: If your question is about Unity make sure you add the Unity3d tag to your question you will get a lot more people who know about Unity's gotchas than if you just do the C# tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your example in the comments, and that this is for Unity, watch [this clip from Unite 2016](https://youtu.be/6vmRwLYWNRo?t=1420). It talks about using Scriptable Objects instead of enums for dictionary keys.

What you would do is have

```
public class Program
{
    protected Dictionary<ScriptableObject, string> dict = new Dictionary<ScriptableObject, string>();
}

public class ProgramChild1 : Program
{
    public void Test()
    {
        dict.Add(MyEnum1.One.Instance, "One");
        dict.Add(MyEnum1.Two.Instance, "Two");
        dict.Add(MyEnum1.Three.Instance, "Three");
        string result;
        dict.TryGetValue(MyEnum1.Two.Instance, out result);
    }   
}

public class ProgramChild2 : Program
{

    public void Test()
    {
        dict.Add(MyEnum2.Four.Instance, "One");
        dict.Add(MyEnum2.Five.Instance, "Two");
        dict.Add(MyEnum2.Six.Instance, "Three");
        string result;
        dict.TryGetValue(MyEnum2.Five.Instance, out result);
    }
}

//Each class goes in to its own .cs file, Put them in two folders `MyEnum1` and `MyEnum2`
namespace MyEnum1
{
    public class One : ScriptableObject
    {
        private static One _inst;
        public static One Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = Resources.FindObjectOfType<One>();
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = CreateInstance<One>();
                return _inst;
            }
        }
    }
}  

namespace MyEnum1
{
    public class Two : ScriptableObject
    {
        private static Two _inst;
        public static Two Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = Resources.FindObjectOfType<Two>();
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = CreateInstance<Two>();
                return _inst;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyEnum1
{    
    public class Three : ScriptableObject
    {
        private static Three _inst;
        public static Three Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = Resources.FindObjectOfType<Three>();
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = CreateInstance<Three>();
                return _inst;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyEnum2
{    
    public class Four : ScriptableObject
    {
        private static Four_inst;
        public static Four Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = Resources.FindObjectOfType<Four>();
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = CreateInstance<Four>();
                return _inst;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyEnum2
{    
    public class Five : ScriptableObject
    {
        private static Five _inst;
        public static Five Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = Resources.FindObjectOfType<Five>();
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = CreateInstance<Five>();
                return _inst;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyEnum2
{    
    public class Six : ScriptableObject
    {
        private static Six _inst;
        public static Six Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = Resources.FindObjectOfType<Six>();
                if (!_inst)
                    _inst = CreateInstance<Six>();
                return _inst;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the reason we inherit from `ScriptableObject` is if you wanted to expose a enum to the designer you could then drag and drop the enum value right in the designer, you could not do this if the enums where just basic classes.

```
public class ProgramChild2 : Program
{
    public ScriptableObject SelectedValue;
    public void Test()
    {
        dict.Add(MyEnum2.Four.Instance, "One");
        dict.Add(MyEnum2.Five.Instance, "Two");
        dict.Add(MyEnum2.Six.Instance, "Three");
        string result;
        dict.TryGetValue(SelectedValue, out result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No boxing, no heap allocations. Very fast. No need to write a specific comparer for each enum.

This version will work on any enum as long as its underlying Type isn't more than 32-bits (so byte, ushort, uint are all fine).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public sealed class EnumComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct Transformer
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public T t;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int int32;
    }

    public static EnumComparer<T> Default { get; } = new EnumComparer<T>();

    private EnumComparer()
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(T a, T b)
    {
        Transformer aTransformer = new Transformer { t = a };
        Transformer bTransformer = new Transformer { t = b };
        return aTransformer.int32 == bTransformer.int32;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T value)
    {
        Transformer valueTransformer = new Transformer { t = value };
        return valueTransformer.int32.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you want to use it with arrays, you'll probably want to make some extension methods and then you can use it like this:

```
bool contained = enumArray.Contains(MyEnum.someValue, EnumComparer<MyEnum>.Default);


public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Contains<T>(this T[] array, T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
        }
        return Extensions.IndexOf<T>(array, value, 0, array.Length, equalityComparer) >= 0;
    }

    public static int IndexOf<T>(this T[] array, T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
        }
        return Extensions.IndexOf<T>(array, value, 0, array.Length, equalityComparer);
    }

    public static int IndexOf<T>(this T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
        }
        if (count < 0 || startIndex < array.GetLowerBound(0) || startIndex - 1 > array.GetUpperBound(0) - count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        int num = startIndex + count;
        for (int i = startIndex; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (equalityComparer.Equals(array[i], value))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was your struct supposed to have two fields with FieldOffset(0)?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a class that implements the interface IEqualityComparer.

```
class MyEnumComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyEnum> { ... }
```

Which means you need to implement both *bool Equals(MyEnum, MyEnum)* and *int GetHashCode(MyEnum)* functions defined by the *IEqualityComparer* interface.

Finally when you are creating your Dictionary, use the constructor overload that receives an *IEqualityComparer* instance, like this:

```
static MyEnumComparer myEnumComparer = new MyEnumComparer();
...
Dictionary<MyEnum, string> dict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>(myEnumComparer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution proposed by [@Executor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303364/2504433) do not work on .Net framework or .Net Core
because of this [Why can't generic types have explicit layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746189/why-cant-generic-types-have-explicit-layout)

But if replace `EnumComparer<T>` from this solution with `ConvertToLong` from [Dissecting new generic constraints in C# 7.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/) it will give solution working on full frameworks.